# Published Web app Auth AD B2C: Error404 for /signin/B2C_1_mysigninoutpolicy'

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am following azure AD B2C auth [example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-5-B2C) which runs fine on local changing appsettings.json to my webapp tenant/app. When I publish to azure the home webpage opens but at pressing Login I don't get to the authorisation window, Fiddler shows:

```
redirect_uri_mismatch
    AADB2C90006: The redirect URI 
    'https://webappname.azurewebsites.net/signin/B2C_1_mysigninoutpolicy' provided in the request is not registered for the client id 'xxxxxxxx'.
```

The user flow policies are registered:
[image]

I think this setup is [b2login.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin) compliant.

a) I create tenant and register the app in portal. At the tenant:

- Azure AD B2C resource name (tenant): tenantName.onmicrosoft.com
- I set App Registration->Reply URL https://webappname.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc
- Also on App Registration->Add ID URI (optional): I left it blank
- Native client: No

b) At my subscription level (not tenant) Azure portal, the published app settings:

- app URL: https://webappname.azurewebsites.net
- Configuration->Application settings: shows WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION and I've added ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT with value "Production".

At the project's appsettings.json, settings are:

```
 "Instance": "https://tenantName.b2clogin.com",
    "ClientId": "XXXXXX",
    "ClientSecret": "XXXXX",
    "Domain": "tenantName.onmicrosoft.com",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/B2C_1_mysigninoutpolicy",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_mysigninoutpolicy",
    "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "B2C_1_myresetpolicy",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": "B2C_1_myeditprofilepolicy", // Optional profile editing policy
    "CallbackPath": "/signin/B2C_1_mysigninoutpolicy"
```

The example does't use "Tenant" so I left it out?
I tried uncommenting the example's Callbackpath but same error:

```
//"CallbackPath": "/signin/B2C_1_sign_up_in"  // defaults to /signin-oidc
```

I restarted the web app and waited a couple of minutes each time I've tested. I browse to test at https://webappname.azurewebsites.net

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirect URI in the application registration *must* match the callback path in the application configuration.

In the above question, the redirect URI is set to `/signin-oidc` but the callback path is set to `/signin/B2C_1_mysigninoutpolicy`, which results in the **redirect_uri_mismatch** error response.

Comment: Saved my day @Chris Padgett , thanks a bunch. I've tested CallbackPath set both on appsettings.json and portal to /signin-oidc/B2C_1_mysigninoutpolicy and also tried set to /signin-oidc and work :)